# send xml.tostring via HTTPService.send() in flex

Tags: asp.net, flex3

```
 public var newtreeItems:XML = <items><page caption="Page"><scene caption="Scene"></scene></page></items>;

private function BtnClick():void{
            var params:Object = {};             
            params["call"] = "WriteXml";
            params["XmlValue"] = newtreeItems.toString();
            Alert.show(xmlValue);
             hsData.send(params);
        }
<mx:HTTPService id="hsData" url="http://localhost/FlexXmlTest/Default.aspx" 
    fault="httpFaultHandler(event)"
    result="httpResultHandler(event)"
    method="POST"
    />
```

---

Asp

```
switch (Request["call"])
            {

                case "WriteXml":
                    WriteXml(Request["XmlValue"]); // "in this method i am using StreamWriter to write as xml file"
                    break;

                case "AnotherMethod":
                    // your method call
                    break;
            }
```

I cant able to post this xml value to that page... on that i am saving as a xml file..but if i send any string value like ("hi how r u") with out any tag means its working fine ..

how to send xml formatted string via HTTPService ?

Answer (score 0):

You can set httpService.contentType to "application/xml"